# Html canvas rotate larger image with aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a code sample where I am adjusting a large image to a smaller size with the canvas matching the size of the image. There is a rotate right functionality that will rotate the image inside of the canvas which will adjust the canvas size. I almost have it perfectly working but the image is perfect size only when original or upside down. I can't get the height to be right ratio when the image is rotated on left or right. Here is my jsfiddle and code which is modified code from a different fiddle. Image is just used as test.

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var canvasWidth = 400;
    var canvasHeight;

    var degrees=0;

    var image=document.createElement("img");
    image.onload=function(){
    canvas.width = canvasWidth;
    canvasHeight = 400 / (image.width / image.height);  
    canvas.height = canvasHeight;
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    }
  

    image.src="https://www.magezinepublishing.com/equipment/images/equipment/Lumix-DMCFZ330-5824/highres/Panasonic-Lumix-FZ330-Wide-P1010001_1438873612.jpg";


     $("#clockwise").click(function(){
     degrees+=90
     if (degrees >= 360) degrees = 0;
     
     if (degrees === 0 || degrees === 180 ) {
         canvas.width = canvasWidth;
         canvas.height = canvasHeight;
     }
     else {
         // swap
         canvas.width = canvasHeight;
         canvas.height = canvasWidth;
     }
     ctx.save();
     // you want to rotate around center of canvas
     ctx.translate(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);
    
     ctx.rotate(degrees*Math.PI/180);
     ctx.drawImage(image, -canvas.width*0.5, -canvas.height*0.5, canvas.width, canvas.height);
     ctx.restore();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" ></canvas><br>
    <button id="clockwise">Rotate right</button>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xarnvbdw/6/)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you just intend to rotate the image, you don't need a canvas for that. Plain CSS will suffice.

Comment: I need the canvas because the rotation is just one piece. I have other logic that will be adding other elements to the canvas to create a new image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember you rotate your image. You are changing the aspect ratio of the image when using the swapped canvas width/height in the image draw call. By your calculations, the original image, rotated, should already fit the canvas. The image you produce is also stretched because of this.

[image]

Use `ctx.drawImage(image, -canvasWidth*0.5, -canvasHeight*0.5, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);`.

Else said, you want to draw the same image, then rotate/translate it with canvas calls. But what you are doing is draw a different sized, stretched image when being rotated 90° or 270° and then rotate/translate that.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I got lost when I was resizing the canvas that my brain was thinking the resize canvas size rather than the same size but rotated. This makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

To rotate an image in 90deg steps.

Rather the use the translate and scale you can rotate the image by directly setting the tranformation matrix.

```
ctx.setTransform(a,b,c,d,e,f);
```

The arguments are as follows

- a,b the vector describing the direction and size of a pixels x axis
- c,d the vector describing the direction and size of a pixels y axis
- e,f the coordinate of the origin (where 0,0 will be)

All these are in canvas pixel coordinates. The default is `a = 1`, `b =0` x axis of a pixel is 1 pixel across, and 0 down,  `c = 0`, `d = 1` y axis 0 pixels across and one pixel down, `e = 0`, `f = 0` origin at the top left.

To rotate the image 90 deg clockwise you want the xAxis to go down the canvas and the y axis to go from right to left. The origin is shifted to the top right of the canvas.

```
ctx.setTransform(
   0,1, // x axis down
  -1,0  // y axis from left to right
  ctx.canvas.height,  // origin x and y to top right
  0,
)
ctx.drawimage(image,0,0);
```

As you are scaling by 0.5 this means the pixels will be half the size, and as you are drawing an image you want the origin so that the image fits the image.

```
// rotate image 90 deg and scale 0.5
ctx.setTransform(
   0,0.5, // x axis down
  -0.5,0  // y axis from left to right
  image.height * 0.5,  // origin x and y to top right
  0,
)
ctx.drawimage(image,0,0);
```

You can do the same for each additional rotation

```
// rotate 180 scale 0.5
ctx.setTransform(-0.5,0,0,-0.5, image.width * 0.5,image.height * 0.5);
// rotate -90 scale 0.5
ctx.setTransform(0,-0.5,0.5,0, 0,image.width* 0.5);
```

The image dimensions for each rotation is as follows

```
// for 0deg and 180 deg rotation
canvas.width = image.width * 0.5;
canvas.width = image.height * 0.5;

// for 90deg and -90 deg rotation
canvas.width = image.height * 0.5;
canvas.width = image.width * 0.5;
```

To restore the transform to the default just set the transform to the identity matrix

```
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
```